# Is there a way to insert data and having references created automatically in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still new to mysql and would want to save time when importing data as follows:

I'd like to import lists of cars from various car dealers.
To increase performance, I have created tables for car makers and car models.
What I'm looking for now is a way to insert the data from a car dealer automatically including adding a car maker and/or a car model in the respective tables plus generating the corresponding ids and to write those ids into the main table.
Here's an example:
the table car_makers contains

| maker_id | maker_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi |
| 2 | Chrysler |
| 3 | Honda |

the table car_models contains

| model_id | model_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | A5 |
| 3 | Civic |
| 4 | Voyager |

Then I get this list (abbreviated to only show the important parts for this question):

| car maker | car model |
| --- | --- |
| Audi | A5 |
| Audi | A3 |
| Chrysler | Pacifica |
| Volkswagen | Beetle |

It should insert

| model_id | model_name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | A3 |
| 6 | Pacifica |
| 7 | Beetle |

into the car_models table and

| maker_id | maker_name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Volkswagen |

into the car_makers table, then insert the list as follows (maker_name and model_name only to clarify, they are not part of the main table)

| maker_id | maker_name | model_id | model_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi | 5 | A3 |
| 1 | Audi | 2 | A5 |
| 2 | Chrysler | 6 | Pacifica |
| 4 | Volkswagen | 7 | Beetle |

This way, new makers / models would automatically be added to these two tables and only the needed reference ids would be inserted into the main table.

I could still go over these two tables to find typos and adjust them later.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please reformat so it's readable.

Comment: Sorry, tried to insert the tables as tables using the structure shown and it worked in the preview but seems to not work here in the actual posting.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in multiple steps.  Let me assume your new data is in a table called `staging` and that you have unique indexes on the names in each of the reference tables:

```
insert into car_makers (maker_name)
    select distinct car_maker
    from staging
    on duplicate key update maker_name = values(maker_name);

insert into car_models (model_name)
    select distinct car_model
    from staging
    on duplicate key update model_name = values(model_name);

insert into main (model_id, maker_id)
    select cmo.model_id, cma.maker_id
    from staging s join
         car_makers cma
         on cma.maker_name = s.car_maker join
         car_models cmo
         on cmo.model_name = s.car_model;
```

Note:  You should not be storing the names in the main table.  The names are available by joining to the reference tables.

Comment: Even if you get the data as a text file consider storing it into a table like staging as it makes the whole import process a lot easier.

Comment: is there a point to "on duplicate key update"?  The primary key will likely be an auto_increment so the main risk is that you already have a particular make in the table, when you try to import it again.  That would still create a 2nd row with the same make but different id, no?  I mean, you fix that in the table with a unique constraint on 'car maker' but then shouldn't it just be ignored?

Comment: @AllanWind . . . I think you are missing this part of the answer:  **you have unique indexes on the names in each of the reference tables**.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Of course I won't add the names to the main table, then the whole point of having the additional tables would be gone. :) That's why I said they were just added to clarify what I have in mind but maybe that confused more than it clarified.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, I did miss that, but that's the point of doing an update then?

Comment: @AllanWind . . . The "update" is a no-op to prevent an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wouldn't it do a superfluous update? ` insert ignore` would be the no-op case (i.e. warnings).  Just wondering about he finer details.

Comment: @AllanWind . . . You can refer to the documentation.  MySQL does not update a row if no data changes.